# how do I determine whether git history is linear?

Tags: git

Given two git commits, how can I to determine, ideally with plumbing commands, whether the history between them is linear?

In other words, I want to know whether I have this:

```
A-B-C-D-E-F-G
```

rather than this:

```
   /-C-\
A-B     -E-F-G
   \-D-/
```

Comment: Adjacently-related: my question on [how to view a git log _as if it was_ linear](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76625363/4561887)

Answer (score 3):

`git log --min-parents=2` will only display commits who have at least 2 parents (e.g : merge commits)

You can run :

```
# for esthetics : --oneline will output one single line per filtered commit
git log --oneline --min-parents=2 A..G

# if output is empty : linear history

# and :
git log --oneline --min-parents=2 A..G | wc -l

# should give you the number of merge commits between A and G
```

Comment: [prahla venkata](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41546204/86072) has given an even better variant. `--min-parents` is actually a flag for the `git rev-list` command, and `git rev-list` has a built-in `--count` flag (to count the number of selected commits).

Comment: Note that `--min-parents` and `--count` handling are shared with `git log`, though `--count` makes no sense with `git log` (so it just gets ignored).

Answer (score 3):

```
git rev-list --min-parents=2 --count A..G
```

will give number of commits having more than one parent.
Count '0' indicates a linear history.

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy to compromise on something higher level than porcelain, you could use [gitpython](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/GitPython/), looking for commits with one or more parents.

```
import git


def is_linear(commit):
    ncommits = len(commit.parents)
    if ncommits == 0:
        return True
    elif ncommits == 1:
        return is_linear(commit.parents[0])
    else:
        return False

repo = git.Repo('.')
print is_linear(repo.commit())
```

Answer (score 0):

"Between" is a slippery notion in graphs.

If you have something like your example, [LeGEC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41545950/1256452) is fine (though I would simplify it slightly further to `git rev-list --count --min-parents=2 A..G` and check for a nonzero result).

But suppose the graph fragment looks like this:

```
A--B--C
       \
        G
       /
D--E--F
```

Is `A..G` to be considered linear?  Here `A` is a root commit but it doesn't really matter, we could use `B..G` or `C..G` just as well.  The issue here is that there is another root commit, `D`, which is reachable from `G` but is not a descendant of `A`.  The commit that is a merge commit that is in the set of commits "reachable from `G`, excluding commits reachable from `A`" is `G` itself.  Or:

```
A--B--C--G
     /
 D--F
   /
  E
```

Here there are three root commits, `A`, `D`, and `E`.  The set of commits reachable from `G` minus the set reachable from `A` leaves all of `B`, `C`, `D`, `E`, `F`, and `G`, and both `C` and `F` are merge commits.

If you wish to constrain the test to "commits that are descendants of `A` and ancestors of `G`, including `G` but excluding `A` itself", add `--ancestry-path` to the check for merges:

```
git rev-list --count --min-parents=2 --ancestry-path A..G
```

This will count the embedded loop in your example as nonlinear, but count my second fragment as linear (commits `C` and `F` are not descendants of `A` in the last graph, for instance).  My first case would not be considered linear here since commit `G` is selected and is a merge commit, so for this particular case, you would have to use `A..G^@` as your range.  (This is a slight correction from earlier: we want *all* parents of `G`, not just the first one; we will rely on `--ancestry-path` to pick the right one(s).)