# How to view a linear `git log` (exclude feature commits), showing only commits to `main` or merges to `main`

Tags: git, git-log

### Quick summary of my question

I have this [`git lg`](https://coderwall.com/p/euwpig/a-better-git-log) output (get this alias in my "Details" section below):

```
*   3333333 - merge of feature branch into `main`
|\  
| * ccccccc - feature branch commit 3
| * bbbbbbb - feature branch commit 2
| * aaaaaaa - feature branch commit 1
|/  
* 2222222 - some other commit
* 1111111 - initial commit
```

I want this `git lg` output:

```
* 3333333 - merge of feature branch into `main` 
* 2222222 - some other commit
* 1111111 - initial commit
```

How can I do that? You might re-title this question: "how to view a `git log` *as if it was* linear".

### Details

I have [this `git lg` alias](https://coderwall.com/p/euwpig/a-better-git-log). It's great! Get it by running this:

```bash
# add `git lg` alias from Coderwall
git config --global alias.lg "log --color --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit"
```

Its output looks like this:

```
*   3333333 - merge of feature branch into `main`
|\  
| * ccccccc - feature branch commit 3
| * bbbbbbb - feature branch commit 2
| * aaaaaaa - feature branch commit 1
|/  
* 2222222 - some other commit
* 1111111 - initial commit
```

Here, I have labeled the two branches `main` and `feature`. Commits `1111111`, `2222222`, and `3333333` are either direct commits to `main`, or merge commits to `main`. Commits `aaaaaaa`, `bbbbbbb`, and `ccccccc` are commits on `feature` branch:

```
v-branch `main`
  v-branch `feature`


*   3333333 - merge of feature branch into `main`
|\  
| * ccccccc - feature branch commit 3
| * bbbbbbb - feature branch commit 2
| * aaaaaaa - feature branch commit 1
|/  
* 2222222 - some other commit
* 1111111 - initial commit
```

**I'd like a "bigger picture" sort of view. I don't care about the individual commits in each feature branch. I just want to see these "main" commits,** whether I run `git log` or `git lg`:

```
* 3333333 - merge of feature branch into `main` 
* 2222222 - some other commit
* 1111111 - initial commit
```

How can I do that? `git lg --merges` or `git log --merges` is closer, but not right. It shows this:

```
* 3333333 - merge of feature branch into `main`
```

But, what I really want is the whole *linear history*, with all commits directly to `main`, or merged to `main`. That would be *as if* I had a squashed linear `git log` history by enforcing `git rebase`+squash+fast-forward merges instead of `git merge` merges.

Anyway, so how can I filter and just get this `git lg` output?

```
* 3333333 - merge of feature branch into `main` 
* 2222222 - some other commit
* 1111111 - initial commit
```

Comment: For the _opposite_ of this question, where you might want to see _only_ the feature branch commits for a given merge commit, see my Q&A here: [In a `git merge`-style workflow, show only the unique commits someone had in their PR (Pull Request) before merging](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77617437/4561887).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for the `--first-parent` option to `git log`. It describes exactly what you're looking for. From the [`git-log` man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---first-parent):

> `--first-parent`
>
> Follow only the first parent commit upon seeing a merge commit. This option can give a better overview when viewing the evolution of a particular topic branch, because merges into a topic branch tend to be only about adjusting to updated upstream from time to time, and this option allows you to ignore the individual commits brought in to your history by such a merge.

Using a local repository as an example, if I run:

```
git log --graph --format='%h' HEAD~5..
```

I get:

```
* 6abb395
*   cb88d06
|\  
| * aa53a16
|/  
*   0abcc50
|\  
| * 1e7bcc6
|/  
*   4e0ab62
|\  
| * fd16fb0
|/  
* 5d7f675
* 6941b71
```

But if I add the `--first-parent` option ("When finding commits to include, follow only the first parent commit upon seeing a merge commit"):

```
git log --graph --format='%h' --first-parent HEAD~5..
```

I get:

```
* 6abb395
* cb88d06
* 0abcc50
* 4e0ab62
* 5d7f675
```

And I think that's the behavior you were looking for.

Comment: I think you missed one: `6941b71` would be below `5d7f675` in the output.

Comment: That's it! `git log` even states this outright, describing exactly the "bigger picture" sort of view I wanted to see!: `--first-parent Follow only the first parent commit upon seeing a merge commit. This option can give a better overview when viewing the evolution of a particular topic branch, because merges into a topic branch tend to be only about adjusting to updated upstream from time to time, and this option allows you to ignore the individual commits brought in to your history by such a merge.`

Comment: @GabrielStaples this is the actual, complete output of the given `git log` command. I did not edit it in any way.

Comment: I see. I've noticed that some `git log` commands, depending on the options, including `git lg`, exclude the initial commit for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Update: [@larsks got it!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76625407/4561887)

### Final answer: how to show a `git log` general summary

```bash
# Show only the primary commits directly to `main`, not the sub-commits on 
# feature branches merged in!
# - this tracks down only the left (first) parent on merge commits,
#   thereby showing a better "overview" or summary of the branch

git lg --first-parent
git log --first-parent
```

---

My initial attempt:

This is a cheesy *partial* answer. It only works with `git lg`, and it requires that the commits I care about begin their `git lg` output lines with the `*` character:

```bash
git lg | grep '^\*'
```

- `^` means "start of the line", and
- `\*` means the `*` character, literally

So, this just looks for a literal `*` char at the start of a line.

<s>I still need help figuring out a better answer.</s>

### See also

1. For the *opposite* of this question, where you might want to see *only* the feature branch commits for a given merge commit, see my Q&A here: [In a `git merge`-style workflow, show only the unique commits someone had in their PR (Pull Request) before merging](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77617437/4561887).
2. I just discovered that this answer mentions `--first-parent` too: [View git log without merge commits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35946023/4561887)