# In a `git merge`-style workflow, show only the unique commits someone had in their PR's (Pull Request's) feature branch before merging

Tags: git, github, gitlab, bitbucket, git-log

I'm working in a code base with a merge-style workflow which uses Bitbucket, GitHub, or Gitlab for pull requests (PRs).

I'd like to see the "right-parent" commits only, or something akin to a `git log --second-parent` output, if such a command existed.

On branch `main`, how can I see the following?:

1. a graphical depiction of the forking and merging of the commits in the branch,
2. a list of only the "primary" commits--ie: the merge commits *to `main`* via a PR (Pull Request), or commits committed directly to `main` with*out* a merge PR (assuming the person had sufficient privileges and the branch wasn't protected), and
3. [most important!] a list of just the unique commits in someone's PR for any given merge commit

Example of branch `main`:

```
*   commit4 (merge commit to `main`, via a PR)
|\  
| * featureCommit2
| * featureCommit1   
|/   
*   commit3
*   commit2
*   commit1 (initial commit)
```

1. For 1. I'd like to see something like the drawing above.
2. For 2. I'd like to see this:

   ```
   * commit4 (merge commit to `main`, via a PR)
   * commit3
   * commit2
   * commit1 (initial commit)
   ```
3. For 3. I'd like to see this:

   ```
   * featureCommit2
   * featureCommit1
   ```

   ...or maybe this too, so I can see the merge commit itself, too:

   ```
   * commit4
   * featureCommit2
   * featureCommit1
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added some additional markers for `commit4^2` and `commit4~` in the commit graph here to make my answer more clear:

```
*   commit4 (merge commit to `main`, via a PR)
|\  
| * featureCommit2 (`commit4^2`, ie: the feature branch the person 
| |                 was working on for the PR)
| * featureCommit1   
|/   
*   commit3 (`commit4~`, ie: branch `main` before the PR above merged in)
*   commit2
*   commit1 (initial commit)
```

### 1. graphical depiction of a branch, showing forking and merges

Use `git lg`, an alias from Coderwall.com: https://coderwall.com/p/euwpig/a-better-git-log

```bash
# Add it as an alias
git config --global alias.lg \
    "log --color --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit"

# Use it
git lg
```

### 2. List of only the "primary" commits

Use:

```bash
git lg --first-parent   # single-line log version
git log --first-parent  # full-log version
```

Either of the commands just above will produce more output information than shown here, but here is the gist of *which commits* will be output in the example from the question:

```
* commit4 (merge commit to `main`, via a PR)
* commit3
* commit2
* commit1 (initial commit)
```

This is from my Q&A here: [How to view a linear `git log` (exclude feature commits), showing only commits to `main` or merges to `main`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76625396/4561887), thanks to [@larsks's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76625407/4561887).

### 3. A list of just the new/unique commits in someone's PR for any given merge commit

This is essentially the *opposite* as 2. above, and took me quite some time to think about and figure out.

Use this:

```bash
# Show everything in commit4's right parent (the feature branch), 
# but NOT in its left parent (branch `main` before the merge)
git lg ^commit4~ commit4^2  

# Show everything in commit4 (the merge commit created by the PR merging, 
# plus the feature branch that was merged), but NOT in its left parent 
# (branch `main` before the merge)
git lg ^commit4~ commit4
```

In a real example, you would use the full or short commit hashes instead of the word `commit4` above. So, it might look like this, for example:

```bash
git lg ^a1b2c3d~ a1b2c3d^2
# or
git lg ^a1b2c3d~ a1b2c3d
```

More specifically:

1. This:

   ```bash
   git lg ^commit4~ commit4^2
   ```

   ...produces this:

   ```
   * featureCommit2
   * featureCommit1
   ```
2. And this:

   ```bash
   git lg ^commit4~ commit4
   ```

   ...produces this:

   ```
   * commit4
   * featureCommit2
   * featureCommit1
   ```

You might think of this as showing only the "right-hand parent" or "right-parent" commits, or as a type of `git log --second-parent` (which doesn't exist) command.

If you go online on GitHub, Bitbucket, or Gitlab to the PR which made `commit4`, you'll see that it shows only these commits, either `commit4` plus `featureCommit2` and `featureCommit1`, or just `featureCommit2` and `featureCommit1`, depending on the online system you are using.

##### Explanation

As I first wrote in my answer here: [How to cherry-pick a single commit, multiple commits, or a range of commits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69472178/4561887):

1. `commit^2` is the immediate **right** parent of the two parents involved in the merge which created `commit`. In this case, **this would be the branch of feature commits that the person who opened the PR was working on before merging their PR.**
2. And `commit~` is the immediate **left** parent of the two parents involved in the merge which created `commit`. In this case, **this would be the `main` branch as it was *before* this PR was merged into `main`.**

The carat (`^`) symbol *in front* of a commit means "not" that commit, or to "exclude" that commit.

So:

1. `commit4` means "commit4",
2. `commit4~` means "one commit before `commit4`", AKA: "`commit4`'s **left** parent" (if `commit4` is a merge commit), and otherwise just "`commit4`'s **only** parent".
3. `^commit4~` means "*not* in `commit4`'s **left** parent", and
4. `commit4^2` means "in `commit4`'s **right** parent".

So:

1. `git lg ^commit4~ commit4^2` means "show me all commits which are in `commit4`'s **right** parent (ie: *excluding* `commit4` itself), but *not* in `commit4`'s **left** parent". This includes all ancestor commits before the specified commit, too, all the way back in time, just as though you had specified a branch instead of a commit hash. And:
2. `git lg ^commit4~ commit4` means "show me all commits which are in or under `commit4` (*including* `commit4` itself), but *not* in `commit4`'s **left** parent". Again, this includes all ancestor commits before the specified commit, too, all the way back in time, just as though you had specified a branch instead of a commit hash.